# Python multiple context managers in one class

Tags: python, with-statement

I would like to be able to write code like this:

```
with obj.in_batch_mode:
    obj.some_attr = "some_value"
    obj.some_int = 142
    ...
```

when I want `obj` to wait with sending updates about itself until multiple jobs are completed. I have hooks on `__setattr__` that take some time to run, and the changes can be sent together.

I do not want to use code like this, since it increases the risk of forgetting to leave batch_mode (which is what the `with` keyword is good for):

```
obj.enter_batch_mode()
obj.some_attr = "some_value"
obj.some_int = 142
...
obj.exit_batch_mode()
```

I have not been able to figure out how to implement this. Just typing `with obj:` (and simply implementing `with` on `obj`) does not read anywhere near as descriptive.

Comment: You need to implement the __enter__ and __exit__ functions in order to use the built in with statement

Comment: Please read the whole question :)

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple context managers"?

Comment: I want to implement multiple context managers on different properties so i can write `with obj.in_batch_mode` and `with obj.in_verbose_mode` etc. instead of the `with obj` example above, which does not read well

Comment: You could keep track of objects returned when issuing .in_batch_mode and if the count is positive, you could have the __setattr__ trigger the hooks. When the object returned from .in_batch_mode is destructed you leave batch mode

Comment: uh, subclass? Or have mode flags, the way `open` does?

Comment: Could you have some mode state in the object that affects the way the object behaves in the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods? It wouldn't be quite as explicit as it sounds like you want since the mode would not necessarily be included in your `with obj:` call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a very simple way to implement context managers is to use the [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) module. Writing a context manager becomes as simple as writing a single yield generator. Before the yield replaces the `__enter__` method, the object yielded is the return value of `__enter__`, and the section after the yield is the `__exit__` method. Any function on your class can be a context manager, it just needs the be decorated as such. For instance, take this simple `ConsoleWriter` class:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sys import stdout
from io import StringIO
from functools import partial

class ConsoleWriter:

    def __init__(self, out=stdout, fmt=None):
        self._out = out
        self._fmt = fmt

    @property
    @contextmanager
    def batch(self):
        original_out = self._out
        self._out = StringIO()
        try:
            yield self
        except Exception as e:
            # There was a problem. Ignore batch commands.
            # (do not swallow the exception though)
            raise
        else:
            # no problem
            original_out.write(self._out.getvalue())
        finally:
            self._out = original_out

    @contextmanager
    def verbose(self, fmt="VERBOSE: {!r}"):
        original_fmt = self._fmt
        self._fmt = fmt
        try:
            yield self
        finally:
            # don't care about errors, just restore end
            self._fmt = original_fmt

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """creates function that writes capitalised attribute three times"""
        return partial(self.write, attr.upper()*3)


    def write(self, arg):
        if self._fmt:
            arg = self._fmt.format(arg)
        print(arg, file=self._out)
```

Example usage:

```
writer = ConsoleWriter()
with writer.batch:
    print("begin batch")
    writer.a()
    writer.b()
    with writer.verbose():
        writer.c()
    print("before reentrant block")
    with writer.batch:
        writer.d()
    print("after reentrant block")
    print("end batch -- all data is now flushed")
```

Outputing:

```
begin batch
before reentrant block
after reentrant block
end batch -- all data is now flushed
AAA
BBB
VERBOSE: 'CCC'
DDD
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are after a simple solution and do not need any nested mode-change (e.g. from STD to BATCH to VERBOSE back to BATCH back to STD)

```
class A(object):
    STD_MODE = 'std' 
    BATCH_MODE = 'batch'
    VERBOSE_MODE = 'verb'

    def __init__(self):
        self.mode = self.STD_MODE

    def in_mode(self, mode):
        self.mode = mode
        return self

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        self.mode = self.STD_MODE

obj = A()
print obj.mode
with obj.in_mode(obj.BATCH_MODE) as x:
    print x.mode
print obj.mode
```

outputs

```
std
batch
std
```

Comment: this could easily be modified to allowing multiple modes by using a list of modes or a bitmap

Answer (score 0):

This builds on Pynchia's answer, but adds support for multiple modes and allows nesting of `with` statements, even with the same mode multiple times. It scales `O(#nested_modes)` which is basically `O(1)`.

Just remember to use stacks for data storage related to the modes.

```
class A():
    _batch_mode = "batch_mode"
    _mode_stack = []

    @property
    def in_batch_mode(self):
        self._mode_stack.append(self._batch_mode)
        return self

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        self._mode_stack.pop()
        if self._batch_mode not in self._mode_stack:
            self.apply_edits()
```

and then I have these checks wherever I need them:

```
if self._batch_mode not in self._mode_stack:
    self.apply_edits()
```

---

It is also possible to use methods for modes:

```
with x.in_some_mode(my_arg):
```

just remember to save `my_arg` in a stack within `x`, and to clear it from the stack when that mode is popped from the mode stack.

---

The code using this object can now be

```
with obj.in_batch_mode:
    obj.some_property = "some_value"
```

and there are no problems with nesting, so we can add another `with obj.in_some_mode:` wherever without any hard-to-debug errors or having to check every function called to make sure the object's `with`-statements are never nested:

```
def b(obj):
    with obj.in_batch_mode:
        obj.some_property = "some_value"

x = A()
with x.in_batch_mode:
    x.my_property = "my_value"
    b(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

Implement helper class

```
class WithHelperObj(object):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __enter__(self):
        self.obj.impl_enter_batch()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.obj.impl_exit_batch()

    class MyObject(object):
        def in_batch_mode(self):
            return WithHelperObj(self)
```

In the class itself, implement method instead of field, to use with the with statement

```
    def impl_enter_batch(self):
        print 'In impl_enter_batch'

    def impl_exit_batch(self):
        print 'In impl_exit_batch'

    def doing(self):
        print 'doing'
```

Then use it:

```
o = MyObject()
with o.in_batch_mode():
    o.doing()
```